# How to setup PHPStorm file watcher for CoffeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, phpstorm, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to run File Watcher in my PHPStorm for CoffeScript, this is my configuration:

[image]

Before i'm trying to change something with this configuration everything was fine, but after that ... I need to compile it to Parent Dir as a scripts.js file, can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

please try something like the following:

Arguments: --output $FileParentDir$ --compile --map $FileName$

Working directory:  $FileDir$

Output Paths: $FileParentDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$FileParentDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.map

Note that if you don't like maps being created (as you are not using them in your watcher), you need to remove '--map' from arguments and ':$FileParentDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.map' from output paths